# Swift, ObjectMapper: path for nested array

Tags: swift

I have json from http://openweathermap.org/, and it looks like this:

```
{
"coord": {
"lon": 4.85,
"lat": 45.75
},
"weather": [
{
"id": 803,
"main": "Clouds",
"description": "broken clouds",
"icon": "04d"
}
],
"base": "cmc stations",
"main": {
"temp": 278.988,
"pressure": 985.88,
"humidity": 92,
"temp_min": 278.988,
"temp_max": 278.988,
"sea_level": 1032.68,
"grnd_level": 985.88
},
"wind": {
"speed": 1.8,
"deg": 355
},
"clouds": {
"all": 80
},
"dt": 1445249394,
"sys": {
"message": 0.0037,
"country": "FR",
"sunrise": 1445234548,
"sunset": 1445273273
},
"id": 2996944,
"name": "Lyon",
"cod": 200
}
```

I'm using Alamofire 3.0 for networking, ObjectMapper for mapping json to model, and AlamofireObjectMapper extension to get model objects from request instead of json. 
Now I need to get weather description, but don't know how to write path for it. Tried ["weather.0.description"], ["weather.$0.description"], but these are not working, and my weather description is nil.

Here is my model:

```
class WCurrentWeather: Mappable {
    var weatherDescription: String?
    var tempriture: Double?
    var clouds: Double?
    var rain: Double?
    var humidity: Double?
    var pressure: Double?
    var sunrise: NSDate?
    var sunset: NSDate?

    required init?(_ map: Map){

    }

    func mapping(map: Map) {
        weatherDescription <- map["weather.0.description"]
        tempriture <- map["main.temp"]
        clouds <- map["clouds.all"]
        rain <- map["rain.1h"]
        humidity <- map["main.humidity"]
        pressure <- map["main.pressure"]
        sunrise <- (map["sys.sunrise"], DateTransform())
        sunset <- (map["sys.sunset"], DateTransform())
    }

}
```

and my request:

```
Alamofire.request(.GET, URL, parameters: params)
            .responseObject { (response: WCurrentWeather?, error: ErrorType?) in
                completionHandler(response, error)
        }
```

Is there any way to get this working.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: How do you store this json? Give more details. Give us code. If you store it in a Dictionary, you can get `description` as `dict["description"]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have forked [ObjectMapper](https://github.com/Hearst-DD/ObjectMapper), and added this functionality, and thanks to Tristan Himmelman it is already merged, so now you can access to nested array elements like this map["weather.0.description"]

Comment: This functionality is now in the master branch of ObjectMapper

Comment: I have a similar issue but I have nested arrays not only at 0 index can you please tell me how to parse this response http://104.236.140.101/energizers/API-JSON/category-details.php

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is:

```
let jsonDict = // You dict

jsonDict["weather"][0]["description"]
```

I am just giving you a direction. You would need to align it with Swift type casting rules. Good luck!